# How to Merge Multilevel Column Dataframes on a Low Level Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-level

I have several small datasets from a databse displaying genes in different biological pathways. My end goal is to find what are the genes showing up in different datasets. For this reason, i tried to make multilevel dataframes from each dataset and merge them on a single column. However, it looks like it is getting nowhere.

Test samples: https://www.mediafire.com/file/bks9i9unfci0h1f/sample.rar/file

Making multilevel columns:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv("Bacterial invasion of epithelial cells.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("C-type lectin receptor signaling pathway.csv")
df3 = pd.read_csv("Endocytosis.csv")

title1 = "Bacterial invasion of epithelial cells"
title2 = "C-type lectin receptor signaling pathway"
title3 = "Endocytosis"

final1 = pd.concat({title1: df1}, axis = 1)
final2 = pd.concat({title2: df2}, axis = 1)
final3 = pd.concat({title3: df3}, axis = 1)
```

I tried to use pandas.merge() to merge the dataframes on "User ID" column:

```
pd.merge(final1, final2, on = "User ID", how = "outer")
```

But i get an error. I can not use droplevel(), because i need the title on top. So, i can see which dataset each sample belongs to.
Any sugesstion?

Comment: You should provide a minimal example (small datasets as text), not require to download a rar archive ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as you want to see which genes appear in different datasets, it sounds like an inner join might be more useful? With User ID as just a single row index.

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("Bacterial invasion of epithelial cells.csv").set_index('User ID')
df2 = pd.read_csv("C-type lectin receptor signaling pathway.csv").set_index('User ID')
df3 = pd.read_csv("Endocytosis.csv").set_index('User ID')

final1 = pd.concat({"Bacterial invasion of epithelial cells": df1}, axis = 1)
final2 = pd.concat({"C-type lectin receptor signaling pathway": df2}, axis = 1)
final3 = pd.concat({"Endocytosis": df3}, axis = 1)

final1.merge(final3, left_index=True, right_index=True)#.merge(final2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Output:

```
    Bacterial invasion of epithelial cells  Endocytosis
    Gene Symbol     Gene Name   Entrez Gene     Score   Gene Symbol     Gene Name   Entrez Gene     Score
User ID                                 
P51636  CAV2    caveolin 2  858     1.3911  CAV2    caveolin 2  858     1.3911
Q03135  CAV1    caveolin 1  857     1.5935  CAV1    caveolin 1  857     1.5935
```

(I've commented out the second merge operation with `final2` as there aren't any overlapping genes between it and the other two, but you can repeat that process with as many datasets as you like.)

Comment: This is very clever. Never thought of it this way.